# user select googlemap location and store it into db

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I'm building custom real estate app. I have two fields in db (mssql2008) `Longitude Latitude` of datatype decimal. Ofcourse in my domain I have same properties

```
public decimal Longitude
public decimal Latitude
```

My question is how can I use google map to enable user to navigate with some kind of pointer inside map to navigate to exact location and app should be store lon and lan data inside db.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Google map has property "center" which lets you to position map. And it is possible to add custom markers to map. Could you clarify your problem?

Comment: Ok, I should be able to use user location from gmap. How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is exactly what you looking for.

```
http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php
```

Simply click on the map on a location and it will provide you with the latitude and longitude in the callout window.

You can find Google maps API at `code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html`

How will you store this info into db is outscope of this question.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Google maps API has these functions that will help you get the lat and lng of the center of the map:

```
var c = map.getCenter();
var lat = c.lat();
var lng = c.lng();
```

You can then submit these values back to the server to store them in the database.